# Reading a configuration file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a configuration file looks like this -

```
<?
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# This file contains all the configuration information

#database connection details for dbo_db
$dbo_db_host1       = 'hostname';
$dbo_db_database1   = 'database_name';
$dbo_db_user1       = 'username';
$dbo_db_password1   = 'password';
$dbo_db_driver1     = 'mysql';
$dbo_db_port1       = '';

#database connection details for dbo
$dbo_dbhost1        = 'hostname2';  /* database server host*/
$dbo_dbname1        = 'database_name2';
$dbo_dbuser1        = 'username2';
$dbo_dbpasswd1      = 'password2';
$dbo_server1        = 'mysql';
$dbo_dbport1        = '';   /* database port no.*/

?>
```

I need to read this file and store certain things (db deatils) into the hash. I need the `dbo_db` details only here.

My script -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = {};

my $conf_file = "in_file.txt";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $conf_file)
    or die "Could not open the file $conf_file $!";

while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    next if !$_ || /^\s*$/;
    next if /^\s*#/;
    if (/^\$dbo_db_/) {
        s@\/\*.*\*\/@@;
        s@#.*$@@;
        eval($_);
        my @line =split(/=/,$_); 
        $line[0] =~ s/\s+$//xm;
        $line[0] =~ s/^\s+//xm;
        $line[0] =~ s/^\$//;
        my $evarstr = "\$hash->{$line[0]} = $line[1]";
        eval($evarstr);
    }
}
print "hash:\n".Dumper($hash);
```

Here script gives an expected result. But I'm looking the standard way to read the config file and store the required details into the hash. Example: I have seen `Config::Tiny` which is core module for Perl which does the similar operation. But how do I skip the certain lines which I don't require while reading.

Perl v5.34.0

Comment: Is that a PHP file?

Comment: @baduker The question seems to be a `How to ...` question which is off-topic on code review because it indicates the code isn't working as intended.

Comment: @Shawn, No. Its a txt file.

Comment: That's what php source files are, yes. Just like perl files are text files...

Comment: Are you trying to read a php config file with perl?

Comment: @turtle No, its a plain file.

Comment: OK do you have the specs of the file format? Do you control the file?

Comment: @turtle Yes, I do control the file.

Comment: "Text file" is not a format. We need to know the format of the file to know which parser to use. The format of that text file appears to be PHP. If you want to run PHP code, you'll need a PHP interpreter.

Comment: Re "*Yes, I do control the file*", So use a proper format, like JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 2):

> But I'm looking the standard way to read the config file and store the required details into the hash.

I have a chapter devoted to config files in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org), but here are a few things you can adjust in your program.

First, get rid of the `eval`s. That's taking anything in the config file and running it as Perl code. If a config key has the same name as another variable in scope, you will have problems.

Your second `eval` is something you just do right away. Use the values that you already have to assign to the hash. I think this solves most of your problem:

```
my $hash;
while( ) {
    ...
    $hash->{$line[0]} = $line[1];
    }
```

But, for this code, you have another big problem. You do some text processing before you try to get the keys and values:

```
    s@\/\*.*\*\/@@;
    s@#.*$@@;
```

For the first you, you are trying to get rid of C-style comments. Those are marked at the beginning and end and can span multiple lines. Consider this:

```
<?

/*
$foo = "bar";
$bar = "137";
*/

$quux = "19";
?>
```

Once you figure that out, how do you handle this?

```
<?

$start = "/*";
$end = "*/";

?>
```

The `#` is even worse because it only needs to show up once:

```
$ignore = "#$%^&";
```

This goes beyond your question, but it is something that this format probably requires. You need a full on parser that tracks state.

But. I think you have a PHP file there. The only thing that is different is the start is `<?` instead of `<?php`. Fix that and the PHP::Include module can load it:

```
use PHP::Include ( DEBUG => 1 );
include_php_vars( '/Users/brian/Desktop/config.php' );
```

Here's the debugging output:

```
OPENING PHP FILE "/Users/brian/Desktop/config.php" FOR FILTER PHP::Include::Vars

ORIGINAL PHP:

<?php
#----------------------------------------------------------------
#
# This file contains all the configuration information

#database connection details for dbo_db
$dbo_db_host1       = 'hostname';
$dbo_db_database1   = 'database_name';
$dbo_db_user1       = 'username';
$dbo_db_password1   = 'password';
$dbo_db_driver1     = 'mysql';
$dbo_db_port1       = '';

#database connection details for dbo
$dbo_dbhost1        = 'hostname2';  /* database server host*/
$dbo_dbname1        = 'database_name2';
$dbo_dbuser1        = 'username2';
$dbo_dbpasswd1      = 'password2';
$dbo_server1        = 'mysql';
$dbo_dbport1        = '';   /* database port no.*/

?>


GENERATED PERL:

my $dbo_db_host1='hostname';
my $dbo_db_database1='database_name';
my $dbo_db_user1='username';
my $dbo_db_password1='password';
my $dbo_db_driver1='mysql';
my $dbo_db_port1='';
my $dbo_dbhost1='hostname2';
```

Now here's the good news. That module is essentially just a Parse::RecDescent grammar that's mostly ready to go. It doesn't know about C comments, but it's not that bad to add that. You could modify it to do what you need, but I'm not going to go through that here.